# Python Type Hinting in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pycharm

I am comming from PyCharm wanting to learn about Python setup with Emacs (Spacemacs).

PyCharm has this feature called [Type Hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) which basically allows specifying types and then get hints based on the specified types. Python 3.5+ has [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) which allows specifying types without comments. Before PEP 484, specifying types was done using comments.

Is there such Type Hinting available with Emacs?

Comment: google search for "mypy for emacs" returns this: https://github.com/lbolla/emacs-flycheck-mypy

Comment: @Anzel, thank you for your answer. This indeed covers the case when Python version is 3.5+. However, is there something for Python <3.5?

Comment: the syntax of type hint is different from PY2, which is shown in comments, but MyPy does support python2 syntax with `--py2` flag. I'm not sure if that flychecker supports that, I'm sure you can install and try out

Comment: @Anzel, I don't think MyPy is used for type hints / auto-complete suggestions.

Comment: are you sure about that? I use MyPy to validate my type hints... although this is in vim.

Comment: there's even an extension in VS Code with MyPy

Comment: @Anzel, you are correct that MyPy validates the code after it is written. My question is more about auto-completing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136763/discussion-between-m3nthal-and-anzel).

Comment: I'm not sure about autocompletion as I don't personally use them, you can checkout the extensions/plugins docs and see if they support it

Answer (score 3):

[Jedi 0.10.0](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#0100-2017-02-03) has added partial PEP 484 support after https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/858

Comment: Sadly, it only supports Python 3. The PEP 484 hinting recommendation for Python 2 (through comments) is not.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question in 2020 and found that there is some better tooling for this. Jedi alone probably won't get you what you want. Instead, you will likely want to use a combo of `elpy`, `flycheck` `flycheck-pycheckers`, `pyflakes`, and `mypy`.

Elpy is the Emacs Python IDE package. flycheck is a general syntax-checking package for Emacs. flycheck-pycheckers works with flycheck to allow you to use more than one Python syntax checker since pyflakes doesn't handle type hints and mypy doesn't handle general syntax – you'll need to use both.

So your steps would be to

1. Install pyflakes and mypy using pip.
2. Install `use-package` in your Emacs config (I'll leave the instructions for this to you).
3. Add the following lines to your init.el or .emacs:

```lisp
;; flycheck
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :config
  (global-flycheck-mode t)
  ;; note that these bindings are optional
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'flycheck-next-error)
  ;; this might override a default binding for running a python process,
  ;; see comments below this answer
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'flycheck-prev-error)
  )
;; flycheck-pycheckers
;; Allows multiple syntax checkers to run in parallel on Python code
;; Ideal use-case: pyflakes for syntax combined with mypy for typing
(use-package flycheck-pycheckers
  :after flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
    (add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-pycheckers-setup)
    )
  (setq flycheck-pycheckers-checkers
    '(
      mypy3
      pyflakes
      )
    )
  )
;; elpy
(use-package elpy
  :after poetry
  :ensure t
  :config
  (elpy-enable)
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'poetry-tracking-mode) ;; optional if you're using Poetry
  (setq elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path 'current)
  (setq elpy-syntax-check-command "~/.pyenv/shims/pyflakes") ;; or replace with the path to your pyflakes binary
  ;; allows Elpy to see virtualenv
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook
        ;; pyvenv-mode
        '(lambda ()
           (pyvenv-mode +1)
           )
        )
  ;; use flycheck instead of flymake
  (when (load "flycheck" t t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))
  )
;; poetry
(use-package poetry
  :ensure t)
```

This solution will get you set up with both Python syntax and type hints in Emacs.

Comment: `(kbd "C-c p")` stand for run Python process its better to set a different key binding for it

Comment: That's a great point @alper, I don't typically use "run Python process" in my workflow so I had overlooked that. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`elpy` was great in the past, I used a setup very similar to that of @jidicula. However, `elpy` no longer works with current versions of `jedi` and this problem has not been fixed for over a year now. Turns out `elpy` is no longer maintained, see https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy

I tried `eglot` and it does the job. However, [`eglot` author insists on using obsolete `flymake` instead of its modern replacement `flycheck`](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/issues/42). `flycheck` can use both `mypy3` and `pyflakes`, whereas `flymake` cannot, so one has to use both `flycheck` and `flymake` in the same buffer, which creates unnecessary friction and new difficulties which I'd rather not waste my time on.

[`lsp-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) appears to be the best choice as of now. It is more popular, has 5 times more contributors and is more flexible and less opinionated because it works with both `flycheck` and `flymake`.

I install `lsp-mode` Python dependencies with:

```
conda install python-lsp-server pylsp-mypy
```

These should also be available with `pip`.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? I appreciate warning that elpy is not actively maintained. I've confirmed that is true. However, you need to explain a bit more about what lsp-mode is, what does it do for you, etc.  Do you need to uninstall elpy packages to do that, for example?  Any config advice?

Comment: @pauljohn32 I defer to `lsp-mode` documentation.